# Get a text log or similar of what an Android App is doing

Tags: android

I'm interested in making an AI that will play/learn Android games. I know I can use MonkeyRunner to "play" (i.e. tap where I need to tap), but is there a way to see what the app itself is doing so that I can program a response to it?

To be clear, I want the program to play a 3rd party game. For example, Flappy Bird - is there a way to "see" the location of the bird and tubes without having to analyze the outputted graphics?

Comment: so you wanna make a robot that plays games ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can monitor app activity by `logcat`

Just use `adb` for it. You can easily monitor by using rooted device.

Just enter `adb shell logcat` in `android terminal emulator app`.